# Load First image on custom Gallery with FadeIn effect

Tags: jquery, html

i get this script to custom build some image gallery:

```
$('#plantas-img a').click(function(){
        image = $("<img />").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        $("#plantas-img .img_big").html(image);
        return false;
    })
```

my html:

```
<div id="plantas-img" class="product-img">
    <div class="img_big">
        <img src="plantas/image_1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap_thumbs_plantas">
        <ul class="thumbs">
            <li><a href="plantas/image_1.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_1.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_2.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_2.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_1.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_1.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_2.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_2.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_1.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_1.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_2.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_2.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_1.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_1.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_2.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_2.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_1.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_1.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="plantas/image_2.jpg"><img src="plantas/thumb_image_2.jpg"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine, but this site have some administrator, so i need to dinamic load inside the `.img_big` div the first `li` image. Another question is: How to put some FadeIn/FadeOut Effect on this script?

Answer (score 0):

To load the first image from the list to the big image, to can do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var image = $("<img />").attr(
       "src", 
       $(".thumbs li:first-child a").attr("href"));

    $("#plantas-img .img_big").html(image);
}
```

To add fade in and out effects, you can use the [jquery fading](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) functions. Just call them on your "onclick" events.

Answer (score 0):

Change javascript to something like this to load first one and fade in

```
$('#plantas-img a').click(function(){
        image = $("<img />").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
        $("#plantas-img .img_big").hide().html(image).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    }).eq(0).click();
```