# Load a "Loading" image for galley first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to load a animated loading gif. It needs to load before the images in the gallery or there is no use having it?

The image will be loaded as a background image via css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="loading.gif" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is possible. Can you share the code what you have tried or a fiddle?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199537/load-first-image-on-custom-gallery-with-fadein-effect

Answer (score 0):

You should first load the "loader" image, and when you're done [asynchronously loading](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Asynchronous-Image-Loading-with-jQuery-Image-Loader-Plugin.html) the gallery images replace the loading image with the loaded images.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying and pasting code, I will like to [link this example on CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/display-loading-graphic-until-page-fully-loaded/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hide the image and switch it in when it loads, behind the image you place your spinner, to do that you wrap the img in a div, in that div you define your spinner. The wrapper uses css to hide the image. Then we use the img onload event to fire a small function (see below) that fades the image in when it has loaded.

Here is how you do it

http://jsfiddle.net/4a1wj359/1/

```
// switches your image in when it loads
var loaded = function(img){
   img.classList.add('loaded');
};

  <div class="img_wrapper">
    <img id="image1" src="http://theselby.com/media/2_28_11_SupremeCoffee7598.jpg" alt="" onload="loaded(this)"/>
 </div>
```

See the fiddle for all the css, note i use a black box not a spinner, you add your spinner image in place of my black background. I also fade the image in after it loads slowly you can change that as you wish.

Comment: If your worried about loading the spinner, just use a CSS defined spinner, their are plenty of generators on the web.